# Magento 2 Page Builder - custom content type missing settings

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2

I have been trying to create a custom content type for the Magento 2 Page Builder.
In order to do this I followed [adobes guide for this](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/page-builder/content-types/create/)

I managed to get the content type up and running correctly without a hitch, then I worked on some other stuff and when I got back to it a week or so later I can not manage to get the settings menu to appear anymore. I have flushed cache, flushes static files and re-rendered, disabled and enabled the module.

It works correctly on other content types as you can see here
[image: working content type]

But when it comes to my quote content type I get the input fields correctly and can input and save the data but the settings refuse to appear anymore.

[image: quote content type]

I don't really know where to start looking into this since I am unsure exactly what generates the setting menu.

I am not sure exactly which files are relevant here to share but I will share the ones I believe can be of help.

**/app/code/Binea/PageBuilderQuote/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/binea_quote.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/content_type.xsd">
    <type name="binea_quote"
        label="Quote"
        menu_section="elements"
        component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type"
        preview_component="Binea_PageBuilderQuote/js/content-type/binea-quote/preview"
        master_component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/master"
        form="pagebuilder_binea_quote_form"
        icon="icon-pagebuilder-quote"
        sortOrder="21"
        translate="label">
    <children default_policy="deny"/>
    <parents default_policy="deny">
        <parent name="column" policy="allow"/>
    </parents>
    <appearances>
        <appearance name="default"
                  default="true"
                  preview_template="Binea_PageBuilderQuote/content-type/binea-quote/default/preview"
                  master_template="Binea_PageBuilderQuote/content-type/binea-quote/default/master"
                  reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/master-format/read/configurable">
            <elements>
                <element name="main">
                    <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                    <style name="border" source="border_style" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-style"/>
                    <style name="border_color" source="border_color"/>
                    <style name="background_color" source="background_color"/>
                    <style name="background_image" source="background_image" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/background-image" preview_converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/preview/background-image"/>
                    <style name="border_width" source="border_width" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/border-width"/>
                    <style name="border_radius" source="border_radius" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/remove-px"/>
                    <style name="margins" storage_key="margins_and_padding" reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/margins" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/margins"/>
                    <style name="padding" storage_key="margins_and_padding" reader="Magento_PageBuilder/js/property/paddings" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/paddings"/>
                    <style name="display" source="display" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/display" preview_converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/style/preview/display"/>
                    <attribute name="name" source="data-content-type"/>
                    <attribute name="appearance" source="data-appearance"/>
                    <css name="css_classes"/>
                </element>
                <element name="quote">
                    <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                    <html name="quote_text" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/html/tag-escaper"/>
                    <css name="quote_css"/>
                </element>
                <element name="author">
                    <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                    <html name="quote_author" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/html/tag-escaper"/>
                </element>
                <element name="author_title">
                    <style name="text_align" source="text_align"/>
                    <html name="quote_author_desc" converter="Magento_PageBuilder/js/converter/html/tag-escaper"/>
                </element>
            </elements>
        </appearance>
    </appearances>
    </type>
</config>
```

**/app/code/Binea/PageBuilderQuote/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_binea_quote_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd" extends="pagebuilder_base_form_with_background_attributes">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pagebuilder_binea_quote_form.pagebuilder_binea_quote_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quote</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <namespace>pagebuilder_binea_quote_form</namespace>
        <deps>
            <dep>pagebuilder_binea_quote_form.pagebuilder_binea_quote_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="pagebuilder_binea_quote_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <dataProvider name="pagebuilder_binea_quote_form_data_source" class="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\ContentType\DataProvider">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName/>
                <primaryFieldName/>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="appearance_fieldset" sortOrder="10" component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/dependent-fieldset">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Appearance</label>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__fieldset-visual-select-large">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <collapsible>false</collapsible>
            <opened>true</opened>
            <imports>
                <link name="hideFieldset">${$.name}.appearance:options</link>
                <link name="hideLabel">${$.name}.appearance:options</link>
            </imports>
        </settings>
        <field name="appearance" formElement="select" sortOrder="10" component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/dependent-visual-select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">default</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <additionalClasses>
                    <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
                    <class name="admin__field-visual-select-container">true</class>
                </additionalClasses>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <elementTmpl>Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/visual-select</elementTmpl>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="AppearanceSourceQuote"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="general" sortOrder="20">
        <settings>
            <label/>
        </settings>
        <field name="quote_text" sortOrder="10" formElement="textarea">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataScope>quote_text</dataScope>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Quote</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="quote_author" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataScope>quote_author</dataScope>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="false">Author</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="quote_author_desc" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataScope>quote_author_desc</dataScope>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="false">Author Description</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="quote_css" sortOrder="40" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">black-quote</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Quote Color</label>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options>
                            <option name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">black-quote</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Black</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">blue-quote</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Blue</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">green-quote</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Green</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="3" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">red-quote</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Red</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="4" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">purple-quote</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Purple</item>
                            </option>
                        </options>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**/app/code/Binea/PageBuilderQuote/view/adminhtml/layout/pagebuilder_binea_quote_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="pagebuilder_binea_quote_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find another solution with less XML and higher effective, I can recommend this https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder/, you can create a new widget (custom content type) by following this guide https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder/wiki/Create-Page-Builder-Widget

Hope this can help